# Cómo puedo convertir una grafica chartjs a pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

necesito mostrar una grafica que hice con chartjs en pdf para que se piueda imprimir, alguien puede darme una idea de como hacerlo con javascript? estoy intentándolo con jspdf.js

```
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<h6>Descargar pdf</h6>

<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'line',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                }]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {}
        });

</script>
```

Comment: tal vez esto te pueda servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140467/page-with-multiple-chart-js-charts-to-pdf

Comment: saludos aquí te dejo un enlace bastante detallado de la forma en que lo logré utilizando chartJS, javascript y Mpdf. ojalá te sirva [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395742/c%C3%B3mo-convertir-una-gr%C3%A1fica-chartjs-a-png/398321#398321)

Comment: No veo que chartjs te retorne un svg, si lo hiciera pues podrias exportar el svg a un PDF pero en la documentacion veo que puedes usar `.toBase64Image()` que te da un blob en png la cual tambien podrias pasar a jspdf

Answer (score 2):

No creo que se pueda hacer eso directamente con la librería de Chartjs, la opción más sencilla que puedes hacer es crear una página en blanco que solo contenga dicha gráfica y luego usar la función de imprimir página a PDF que traen todos los navegadores por defecto. Otra opción que encontré por intenet fue usar CSS para limitar que partes de la página quieres imprimir a solo tu gráfica.

Encontré también un [script en CodePen](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/peqVOM), de una pregunta, que imprime una página con graficas de Chartjs.

Mira aquí un ejemplo de otra [pregunta que se realizó](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417248/how-to-export-google-chart-in-pdf) usando jsPDF y Google Chart.